# Getting crash in xcode 11.3 viewcontroller getting nill

Tags: swift, crash, xcode11.3

Getting error :: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: ' returned nil from -traitCollection, which is not allowed.

It is crashing in this method 
`func carbonTabSwipeNavigation(_ carbonTabSwipeNavigation: CarbonTabSwipeNavigation, viewControllerAt index: UInt) -> UIViewController {
 let sb = UIStoryboard.init(name: storybordname, bundle: nil)
        var viewcontroller:UIViewController!
        viewcontroller = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: controllername)
        return viewcontroller
}`
When i Checked after putting breakpoint its crashing on the first line `super.viewDidLoad()`

Comment: Add the details like when it got crashed, code that executed before the crash. Add the Exception Breakpoint and run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your viewdidload code in disptachQueue

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3, execute: {
               // Your Code
  })
```

Like this...